# Custom Control in Scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, scrollviewer

My Question is how I can put a List of ViewModels of a custom-control into a Scrollviewer which are dislpayed with an itemtemplate. I read something about Virtualizingstackpanels and itemcontrol, but I don't really understand this.

If anybody can help me this would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want multiple instances of the same view model in a scroll viewer you would need to do some thing like this

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public string SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

in your view use an ItemsControl and provide a DataTemplate and bind it to the list of view models.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfViewModels}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

here the datatemplate is a simple grid with a textblock, you can also use your own custom control there

You can read more about items control [here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)